# Relative Paths not working on apache2 web server

Tags: html, apache, debian, relative-path

Good evening!

I'm pretty new to Linux and Apache and I have a problem with relative paths. I developed my website locally on a Mac, using relative paths and everything worked fine. My files are in a folder with following subfolders:

> - sites
> - css
> - images

Now I'm trying to set up my website on a Linux server running Debian. Almost everything worked out perfectly and I can reach my index.html through the internet. But obviously, relative paths are not working, since I placed my images, my css-file and my other sites in above subfolders, which I try to access with relative paths, but actually they are not working. When I try to access another site (about.html) which is in the sites-folder, I just get this error:

> 404 Not Found The requested URL /sites/about.html was not found on
>   this server.

For example, from my index.html, I'm trying to access my css-file with this path:

```
../css/standard.css
```

I've also implemented external paths, these are working correctly. I'd really appreciate any help or clues. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the mistake is in the path:

If index.html is in folder where folders "sites, css, etc" are stored, you have to use

```
css/standard.css
```

instead of

```
../css/standard.css
```